# How can I execute list of commands from a file in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a file "commands.txt" with some commands in it for example:

```
pwd
wc -l commands.txt
```

And when I run the following command, its not executing the commands.

```
export IFS=$'\n' # I did this so that I could avoid breaking up the command line from the file
for i in `cat commands.txt`; do
    $i
done
```

Comment: The normal way to execute the commands in a file is either `bash commands.txt` (executed in a sub-shell) or `. commands.txt` or `. ./commands.txt` (executed by the current shell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are setting `IFS` to `\n`, your second line `wc -l commands.txt` is not being word-split correctly and is being treated as a single command instead of the command `wc` followed by parameter `commands.txt`. Do not set `IFS`, use a `while` loop instead

```
while read -r com; 
do 
    $com; 
done < commands.txt
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering! It works. Is there a way to break up the commands if they are all in the same line with a delimiter ? For example: "ps -aef | wc -l commands.txt | uname -a" (Pipe is being used a delimiter and not part of the command)

Comment: What delimiter?  If it is a semicolon, there's no need; if it is an ampersand, there's might not be any need.  Otherwise, why make life painful for yourself -- generate the file with separate commands on separate lines. Or, at least make life tolerable by using semicolon as the separator.  And note that the simplest way to execute the commands in a file is either `bash commands.txt` (executed by a sub-shell) or either `. commands.txt` or `. ./commands.txt` (executed by the current shell).

Comment: @rsr, `while read -d'|' -r com;  do      $com;  done < commands.txt; if [[ "$com" ]]; then $com; fi`

Comment: Got it ! Thanks very much. Using "read" is the key. Before I was using for line in `cat commands.txt` .... instead when I use while read line ... done < commands.txt it works.